# Using session.setAttribute in a deployed system

Tags: java, session

I have a system that is deployed with the link `http://192.168.2.6:8484/DTR` and upon logging in, it stores the user's info via `session.setAttribute("user", user);` However, when another user logs in, it overwrites the info of the first user as it again calls `session.setAttribute("user", user);`. So how can I really save the user's info so that more than two people can access the system at the same time?

This is what is currently happening:

I have two websites that are open.

1. I login in the `first` website (username: user1). Shows `Hello, user1`
2. I login in the `second` website (username: user2). Shows `Hello, user2`
3. I refresh the `first` website. It will now show `Hello, user2`

So how can I enable multiple users to access the website?

Comment: are both the users logging from the same system and same browser?

Comment: Yes, same system and same browser

Comment: if it same browser it cannot be different user i.e both will have same JSESSIONID and hence session set attribute will get overridden. Try with different browser

Comment: @nubteens then its not possible,try with different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the reason is both the users are logged in from the same browser and same system. So the JSessionId is same and hence the attributes are overriden.

**Solution**:Try with a different browser

Answer (score 1):

You first get user attribute and set it if it's not there and session is new

```
user = session.getAttribute("user");

if (user == null&& session.isNew())
   session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

Also please check if you are getting different session for different users session.getId() ... if not it might be the problem JSESSIONID cookie. The servletcontainer set a Cookie in the Set-Cookie header of the HTTP response with JSESSIONID as cookie name and the unique session ID as cookie value.

Comment: But that still saves only 1 identity of user, right?

Comment: @nubteens correct because each user will have it's own session object